# Synonyms of tags don't display the tag wiki

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

When you view the tags, any synonyms don't have a wiki:

[image: screen shot]

[10k](/questions/tagged/10k) is a synonym of [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools). Why does [10k](/questions/tagged/10k) not display the [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) tag-wiki?

Edit: It is the same on other sites.

[Ask Ubuntu:](http://askubuntu.com)

[image]

Is this to make it easier to distinguish between them?

To me I (I've just started editing tag wikis on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)) I then click on it to edit it to create a wiki, and it redirects me to the main tag-wiki-editing page.

(As a side point it doesn't have the number, but I think that that has already been answered here, and not having the number does help distinguish it as a synonym.)

If this is to distinguish tag synonyms, and the wiki isn't wanted there, could it instead look something like this, where the fact that it is a synonym is clearly displayed:

[image: suggested tag display]